# aside from his financial situation

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

a. Aside from his financial situation, he has a lot to be grateful for.

b. Aside from his financial situation, he has a lot of other things to be grateful for.

c. Aside from his financial situation, there is a lot for him to be grateful for.

d. Aside from his financial situation, there are a lot of things for him to be grateful for.

Is his financial situation good or bad?
Does 'aside from' mean 'except for' or 'in addition to'?

Many thanks.

Comment: See: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aside%20from

Comment: The "other" in option b ensures that the "aside from" in that sentence means  "besides."

Answer (score -1):

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/aside), *aside from* works as a phrasal preposition, and mean **except for**.

(A), (C) and (D) all mean his financial situation is **bad**, but in (B), his financial situation is **good**, as it's one of *a lot of other things* he has to be grateful for.

Comment: Thank you. My problem is that the expression seems to have two meanings https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aside%20from